# How to Run Selenium code in webtest?

Tags: webtest

I am new to webtest and I read that it is possible to record script in selenium and then run it via webtest/fitnesse. I have got webtest and selenium installed and configured. Is there specific format of code that suites webtest? Any help regarding this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The doc is now more complete: http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/modules/sel.html

You need to run `java -jar selenium-server.jar`

Then write your test like with the TestApp but using SeleniumApp

Comment: http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/modules/sel.html just gave me 404 and I'm somehow interested in webtest + Selenium. Any ideas, where is it now? Was it cut out of the main repo as webtest-selenium?